# asp.net: get user input on treeview checked

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am allowing a user to check the checkboxes associated with nodes in my treeview.

I would like to prompt the user for their input as soon as a specific node is checked. 
For Example:

```
if node#2 is checked then get user input
```

1. how do i do this? is the best way c# with javascript? 
    if so , then how?
2. how would i get a list of selected notes after submit button is clicked?

Comment: @Asdfg i have flagged you so that the moderator removes your picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//get a list of selected nodes after submit button is clicked
 protected void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
           if (this.tree.CheckedNodes.Count > 0)
            {
                // Iterate through the CheckedNodes collection and display the selected nodes.
                foreach (TreeNode node in tree.CheckedNodes)
                {
                   Response.Write(node.Value + "<br />"); 
                }
            }

            else
            {
                Response.Write("No node selected.");

            }
}
```

To get the selected node when user check a node you have to fire postback in javascript in head tag
Like

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function postBackByObject() {
            var o = window.event.srcElement;
            if (o.tagName == "INPUT" && o.type == "checkbox") {
                __doPostBack("", "");
            }
        }

</script>
```

and put above code inside TreeNodeCheckChanged event of Treeview
 like

```
protected void tree_TreeNodeCheckChanged(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{

        if (tree.CheckedNodes.Count > 0)
        {
            // Iterate through the CheckedNodes collection and display the selected nodes.
            foreach (TreeNode node in tree.CheckedNodes)
            {
                Response.Write (node.Value + "<br />");

            }
        }

        else
        {
            Response.Write("No items selected.");

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to just handle an OnChange event of each CheckBox with a JavaScript function, which in turn is displaying a prompt box on select - whose input then gets saved in an associated Hidden field (or data-* attribute in HTML5), which gets cleared on unselect.

Then on submit in C# you iterate through all the CheckBox controls for a checked attribute, and all Hidden fields (or data-* attribute in HTML5) for their input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
treeview.Attributes.Add("onclick","prompt(this);");
```

on `Page_Load` this will bind a javascript funciton prompt(sender); to your treeview, & in `prompt()` function you can find which element raised the event by using this & sender or you can use 
event/e to get information about event raising element, 
[for more info on event go here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html)

if you need your user to provide a good responsive experiece then javascript is best way to do it.